# how to get the model name of the product from the product name in php/magento?

Tags: php, magento, tags

I have a products like Nikon Coolpix L30 20.1 MP Digital Camera and Dell Inspiron 15 3521 Laptop. So I need to get the model name L30 and 3521 from the product names. Is that possible in php?

Comment: if you have crated a custom attribute. then you can fetch if from $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);  and then $modelName = $_product->getModelName();

Comment: Thank you,but i have to get the model name from the product name or description,later i can insert into database as an attribute.